# Spiderman: Far From Home - Disney or Sony Rights?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-far-from-home

I have just watched the *Spider-Man: Far From Home* trailer, and I'm confused. If this is an MCU-connected film, does Disney/Marvel own the rights? Or does Sony Pictures?

I thought Disney/Marvel owned the MCU films/stories, but the trailer is put out by Sony Pictures, which I didn't think Disney owned. Am I mistaken?

Who actually owns this film?

Comment: Spiderman is licensed to Sony. Through an agreement Spiderman has been allowed to take part in the MCU.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Sony Pictures has film rights to the character.

> Marvel has owned Spider-Man since his inception. They do, and have always, owned Spider-Man.
>
> If you’re asking about the film rights specifically, that’s more complicated.
>
> Disney owns Marvel. Marvel owns the Spider-Man character. Every time
> someone purchases a Spider-man backpack or lunchbox or T-shirt, Disney
> is making money on that sale.
>
> What Disney does not have are the film rights to the character. Sony
> Pictures does. What this means is that Marvel Studios cannot just go
> and create a Spider-Man film or have spider-Man appear in another film
> by itself. They did negotiate a deal with Sony to allow Spider-Man to
> appear in the Marvel Cinematic Films. That is why you see him in
> Avengers: Infinity War, Captain America: Civil War, & Spider-Man:
> Homecoming.
>
> Marvel had sold film rights for a number of its characters to various
> studios over the years. Most of those have lapsed or returned to
> Marvel Studios / Disney. If the acquisition of Fox is completed -
> Spider-Man will be about the last major character that Disney/Marvel
> does not have the film rights.
>
> Beyond film rights, Marvel had sold the rights to their characters to
> be used in theme parks to Universal Studios. The Universal Orlando has
> a super hero land that includes a Spider-Man ride. Universal never
> created similar lands or rides outside of Florida so the use of the
> rights lapsed elsewhere. What this means is that Disney is free to use
> Marvel characters in all of its theme parks EXCEPT the ones located in
> Orlando. There’s an Iron Man ride in Hong Kong and a Guardians of the
> Galaxy ride in California for example. The rules are a bit nuanced -
> so EPCOT is getting a Guardians of the Galaxy ride, presumably because
> the rights that Universal has are only for characters they already had
> in use (so no Avengers, X-men, or Spider-Man). Universal can also only
> use the comic book/cartoon versions of the characters. They do not
> have rights to show Robert Downey, Jr as Iron Man in their theme park,
> for example.

[Source](https://www.quora.com/Does-Disney-Marvel-actually-own-Spider-Man-now?no_redirect=1)

Comment: That would also explain why the X-men haven’t shown up in the MCU although I suppose it wouldn’t make sense for them to even if Disney gets the rights to them

Comment: @MissouriSpartan I really hope that Disney will get rights of Fantastic Four — can't wait to see this.

Comment: Truth. Granted I’ve often wondered how they would integrate the F4 into the MCU. It’d have to be post-EndGame for sure

Comment: @MissouriSpartan They can just turn to dust and keep silence until Avengers defeat Thanos :)

Comment: lol good point!